# Best practices to have a test base class - .NET

Tags: .net, testing, xunit

I'm starting to write tests for an app, something like:

```
namespace API.Test
{
    public class HealthCheckTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public HealthCheckTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _httpClient = factory.CreateDefaultClient(new Uri("http://localhost/healthcheck"));
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task HealthCheck_ReturnsOk()
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("");

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, I got more controllers so I want to "reuse" the client for example. What do you think it's a better approach.

- Abstract class initializing constructor
- Class and instantiate in constructor like composition.
- Other

Answer (score 0):

Other. What you actually do depends on what you test, what you want to configure and your personal preferences. In this case though the only thing that could be abstracted is the call to `CreateClient` or `CreateDefaultClient` which isn't much. There may not be any need to cache that instance either.

Many tests create a separate `Application` class that inherits from `WebApplicationFactory<>` allowing you to override the configuration or add extra members that may be useful.

[In these tests](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/tree/main/tests/MinimalApiPlayground.Tests) for example, a [PlaygroundApplication](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/main/tests/MinimalApiPlayground.Tests/PlaygroundApplication.cs) class is used that sets the environment and replaces the configured DbContext with one that uses in-memory SQLite. That repo demonstrates .NET 6 minimal APIs so it uses `Program` instead of `Startup` but that doesn't affect the tests at all:

```
internal class PlaygroundApplication : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    private readonly string _environment;

    public PlaygroundApplication(string environment = "Development")
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseEnvironment(_environment);

        // Add mock/test services to the builder here
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddScoped(sp =>
            {
                // Replace SQLite with in-memory database for tests
                return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TodoDb>()
                    .UseInMemoryDatabase("Tests")
                    .UseApplicationServiceProvider(sp)
                    .Options;
            });
        });

        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }
}
```

This class is [used in tests directly](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/MinimalApiPlayground/blob/main/tests/MinimalApiPlayground.Tests/Examples.cs). It's not even used as a class fixture :

```
[Fact]
public async Task GET_Root_Responds_OK()
{
    await using var application = new PlaygroundApplication();

    using var client = application.CreateClient();
    using var response = await client.GetAsync("/");

    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    Assert.Equal("Hello World!", await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

After that, it's a matter of style and convenience. You can have:

- Multiple such classes with separate configurations. Useful if the configurations are complex and/or repeating, eg for different scenarios, and you don't want to litter the tests with the config.
- A single one that's parameterized through constructor options. Useful if there are few options. If there are too many options, it's probably time to split it into separate classes. Configuring an ultra-flexible class can be a bigger hassle than creating a few different specialzed types
- A base `TestApplication` class with common configuration and specialized derived classes for multiple scenarios.

All options can be used as fixtures. You can combine any of these options with a `Theory` to run the same test using different configurations.